# Orientation and paper size when printing to PDF from PowerPoint

Tags: macos, pdf, printing, microsoft-powerpoint

When I want to save my .ppt slideshow to pdf I use the print function. I have set the paper size to the slide size and orientation to landscape (as is the document itself) in page setup > options

However, when I go to print the 'paper' is oriented as portrait and I can't change the orientation in the printer dialogue - the sides of my slides are being cut off.

I'm using Powerpoint 2008 for Mac.

Answer (score 2):

If you click *File » Save As…* and then select *PDF* as format, this achieves exactly what you want — there's no need to go through the *Print* dialog:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sure! Since you're new: you can accept this answer by clicking the green checkmark next to it. Welcome to Super User! :)